# What is the running time of an O(n log n) sort done n times?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, logarithm

Is it O(n^2 log n)? Can you show how it is derived? Is O(n^2 log n) the same as O((n^2) * (log n))?

Comment: Actually it is O((n^2) * (log n))...

Comment: Is this a homrwork? Basic math and wikipedia are enough to answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: Guys, power takes preceence over multiplication... parentheses are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something `n` times takes `O(n)` time. And `n log n` is just another way of writing `n * log n` So we get:

```
  O(n) * O(n * log n)
= O((n) * (n * log n)) 
= O(n * n * log n)
= O(n^2 * log n)
```

Yes, the two ways of writing it that you have shown are the same. This is, however, something completely different: `O(n^(2 log n))`

Answer (score 3):

**Rigorous derivation**:

By definition

```
T(n) = O(n Log(n)) <=> for some N and C,  n > N => T(n) < C.n.log(n).
```

Then obviously

```
for these N and C, n > N => n.T(n) < C.n².log(n)
```

which implies

```
n.T(n) = O(n²log(n)).
```